# MVC EditorFor model binding for multiple edit forms on one page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a class called `CategoryModel`, one of the properties of which is a list of objects of the same type.  So `CategoryModel.Categories` is of type `List<CategoryModel>`.

On the category index page, I display an editor for each category so that the user can change any of the category names without having to go to a dedicated page to do so.  Like so:

```
<ul id="categories>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categories)
</ul>
```

And the editor template for `CategoryModel` looks like this:

```
<li class="folder">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Category", new { id = Model.Key }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajaxoff"})) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Key)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentKey)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Sequence)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IncludeDeleted)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "catName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="icon save" />
    }
</li>
```

The problem I have is that submitting the form does not bind correctly to the `Edit` action of the `CategoryController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CategoryModel category)
{
    // At this point all properties in category are null
}
```

If I check the names on the hidden fields and textboxes, they are labelled based on their position in the current category (e.g. `Categories[0].Name`).  If I create a dedicated edit view, however, they are simply named according to the field name (e.g. `Name`).

I have tried changing the controller to accept a list of Categories:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<CategoryModel> categories)
{
    var category = categories.First();
}
```

This works if I submit the very first category, but none of the others (in those cases `Categories` is null).

I have also tried changing how I display my EditorFor, by doing this:

```
<ul id="categories>
    @foreach (var cat in Model.Categories)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => cat);
    }
</ul>
```

Which changes the field names to be the same for each category (e.g. all category names are called `cat.Name`), which I believe is a step in the right direction.

So how do I bind correctly to my controller?  I realise that I could submit the whole parent category and then save each subcategory, but this seems like a very inefficient way to submit a single change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered how to do this.  There is an overload for `Html.EditorFor` that allows you to specify the `htmlFieldName` property (the third parameter in the example below):

```
@foreach (var cat in Model.Categories)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => cat, null, "");
}
```

This renders all of the field names without any prefix and allows me to submit any single category successfully.

Comment: I did this but I still get [0] and [1] after the field names, how did you deal with that?

Comment: I didn't get the problem you described.  If you used @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categories, null, "") instead of the loop above, you would get [0] and [1] before the field names, however, because you are passing an array to the EditorFor method instead of an individual model.

Answer (score 0):

Your Edit action accept CategoryModel category so you need to reset model prefix for right binding. For this you need to create your own extension method for HtmlHelper like this:

```
public class BeginHtmlScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
        private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        public BeginHtmlScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

            previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        }
    }
    public static class MyHtmlExtensions
    {
        public static IDisposable BeginHtmlScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            return new BeginHtmlScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }
    }
```

And then use it inside your editor template:

```
@using (Html.BeginHtmlScope(""))
{
   <li class="folder">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Category", new { id = Model.Key }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajaxoff"})) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Key)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentKey)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Sequence)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IncludeDeleted)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "catName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="icon save" />
    }
</li>

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same issue as the foreach loop - the field names are Categories[0].Name, Categories[1].Name etc, and the CategoryModel does not bind to the Edit action.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question. I've edited my answer.